# How to log something to pstore in the linux kernel with C code?

Tags: android, c, linux, kernel

The [pstore](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/post/pstore-linux-kernel-persistent-storage-file-system) is a mechanism for logging things that is persistent, so it's used a lot in Android phones.

I want to use this to log things in the kernel, since my phone is hard to debug. Is there some code that I can use to debug directly to the pstore? If so, how and after which kernel line execution I can use it?

Comment: The link you added has a ton of info. It puts the tail of dmesg into pstore you can use `printk`. I'd try that first to see what it does.

Comment: @CraigEstey the link is for tuning the pstore through the terminal. I want to write code in the kernel which prints to the pstore

Comment: From the link: _For example, if the Linux kernel dies, the dmesg tail, is written to pstore._ `dmesg` prints out the last N lines that come from either the `syslog` program/daemon _or_ `printk` in the kernel. So, doing `printk` will put stuff that shows up in `pstore`. Did you even try this?

Comment: @CraigEstey yes I tried, my pstore is always empty, so I thought there was a specific way to do it